# How can I show that a representation of $S_n$ is reducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Considering the representation of $S_n$ where the objects being permuted are the basis vectors of an $n$ dimensional vector space

$$ |1 \rangle, |2 \rangle, \:... \:, |n \rangle$$

If the representation operator $D$ takes $|j \rangle$ to $|k \rangle$, the matrix elements of this representation are

$$\langle l|D|j \rangle = \delta_{kl}$$

I started finding the projection operator into the trivial representation but I don't know how to proceed from there/if it is the right path. I am just starting to learn group theory from the book *H. Georgi - Lie Algebra In Particle Physics* and any help would be appreciated. Tahnks.

Comment: Hint: There is a one-dimensional subspace, which is fixed by every permutation. What linear combination of basis vectors does not change, under any permutation?

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{n} (| 1 \rangle + ... + |n \rangle)$

Comment: Yes, or even just $\lvert 1 \rangle + \cdots + \lvert n \rangle$. So this one-dimensional subspace is a subrepresentation. Since every matrix in your representation is orthogonal, perhaps try to find the orthogonal complement of this subspace too.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** If we denote $$\Bbb V := \operatorname{span}\{|1\rangle, \ldots. |n\rangle\},$$ the representation is a map $S_n \mapsto \operatorname{End} \Bbb V$. Suppose the action of $S_n$ fixes $\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i | i \rangle$. What can we say about the coefficients $a_i$?

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding your resoning. Could you elaborate a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: Consider the question in my hint separately from the original question then.

Comment: Then we can say that they are eigenvalues of $S_n$